# How can I get the current price using IB API

Tags: python, tws, ib-api

I have this code, and I need to store in a variable the last price, how can i do?

```
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):
         EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
         if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
                print('The current ask price is: ', price)


app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

#Create contract object
apple_contract = Contract()
apple_contract.symbol = 'AAPL'
apple_contract.secType = 'STK'
apple_contract.exchange = 'SMART'
apple_contract.currency = 'USD'


app.reqMktData(1, apple_contract, '', False, False, [])
```

I need to save in a variable the current price

Comment: What's `app`? Provide a reproducible example. You can write the value in the class's instance variable.

Comment: Sorry, app = Ibapi()

Comment: You mean `IBapi()`?

Comment: Yes, just edited the code

Comment: Your code still says `Ibapi`, not `IBapi`.
You can create an instance variable in the class and store the value there.

Comment: I don't have much experience,  you mean to create a variable under init function? but then how can i get the price with price = app.reqMktData(1, apple_contract, '', False, False, []) ?

Comment: `app.sleep(1)` at the end of code should solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the prices are printed, I just want to save in a variable the command that get the price

Comment: `x = app.reqMktData(1, apple_contract, '', False, False, [])` `print(x)` try this.

Comment: I tried but it prints 'None'

Answer (score 0):

here's an idea considering your given code:

```
req_id = 1

def get_reqId():
    global req_id
    return (req_id + 1)

def run_loop():
    app.run()
 
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    market_data = {}
    request_mapping = {}
    def __init__(self):
         EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
         if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
                print('The current ask price is: ', price)
                symbol = self.request_mapping[reqId]
                self.market_data[symbol] = price

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)
#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()
time.sleep(1)
#Create contract object
apple_contract = Contract()
apple_contract.symbol = 'AAPL'
apple_contract.secType = 'STK'
apple_contract.exchange = 'SMART'
apple_contract.currency = 'USD'

request_id = get_reqId()

app.request_mapping[request_id] = 'AAPL'
app.reqMktData(1, apple_contract, '', True, False, [])
time.sleep(2)
print(app.market_data['AAPL'])
```

notes:

- start in thread so you don't block main threads execution
- in IBapi class, define dictionaries for market data and request
  mapping
- use get_reqId() to get unique reqId's for mapping purposes
- map each requestID to it's symbol before executing the reqMktData
  function
- changed reqMktData's snapshot parameter to True